# creating a widget in rails with key validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've started coding up a widget controller so that I can have my users share their categories and the widget would display articles in that category; I've followed a few available resources but nothing specific to what I need.

Right now I'm just trying to get my `WidgetController` to work and validate if a valid key is enter or not; if so then display the view, if not `render 'something'` as a text; however I'm getting no where and getting error such as `no action` or `no route matches` I'm hoping someone can help and answer this question to me. So far I've got the following;

```
# Controller Widget
class WidgetController < ApplicationController
   layout false
   session :off

   before_filter :validate_key, :only => [:category_bin]

   def category_bin
      #list articles but for now render text
      render 'articles'
   end

   protected

   def validate_key
     if params[:key] == '01010101'
        return
     else
        render 'not valid'
     end
   end
end

#Routes
SomeApp::Application.routes.draw do

  match '/:controller/:action/:key'

end

#Browser
In the browser I visit the url like my iFrame would; http://localhost:3000/widget/category_bin/01010101 (this would render success and render my `articles` text ), http://localhost:3000/widget/category_bin/01010102 (would render `not valid` text and display nothing but that)
```

Comment: What's the exact error are you getting?

Comment: No route matches "http://localhost:3000/widget/category_bin/01010101"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard route isn't very useful, try creating an explicit route like

```
get '/widget/category_bin/:key', to: 'widget#category_bin'
```

P.S - as a convention, controller names are usually plural, i.e `widgets` not `widget`.

P.P.S - `rake routes` from the command line is a really useful tool to see what rails thinks your routes are

P.P.P.S you may need to call `return` explicitly from your before filter, otherwise it will render 'not valid' (should be `render plain: "not valid"` btw) and then continue to render articles.

Comment: actually figured that before you posted as I noticed my `session :off` was causing issues but isn't that to bypass any user sessions needed with login. Little confusing.